# steam miss 32 bit library

Tags: steam

When I run steam, it reports following error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libXrandr.so.2
libXrender.so.1
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libgio-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpulse.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libva.so.2
libvdpau.so.1
libva.so.2
libva-x11.so.2
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
```

I'm sure that all those packages are installed correctly. for example:

```
$ find /usr/ -name libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
```

Any idea to fix that?

Comment: Steam may be looking in <your home>/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6  for example. Does that file exist?  If not, try reinstalling steam.

Comment: @ubfan1 No, but I do have:.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6, and I don't have folder debian-installation under .steam